# How can I remove black borders from VideoCapture?

Tags: python, opencv, camera

My problem is about correctly configuring openCV, NOT about image processing. Every frame I get with VideoCapture() contains unwanted black borders.

I already tried resizing frames, but openCV simply adjusts the borders to the new size.

It takes no more than this to see the black borders:

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, frame = camera.read()
cv2.imshow("Camera", frame)
```

Here you can see what I get

[image: Here you can see what I get]

Comment: do you have the same problem in other programs ?  maybe problem is hardware or its configuration.

Comment: Try initialising the camera to output a different size of frame. The default height and width of OpenCV may not match any framesize your camera is capable of.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I've already tried that, as I stated in the question. I did it this way: camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0) camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640) camera.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480) after checking: print('Width: ' + str(camera.get(3)))
print('Height: ' + str(camera.get(4)))

Comment: Sorry, your question said you have tried resizing the frames which would mean you acquire them at one size and then change it than you specified a different size of frame to acquire. Anyway, that didn't work so maybe you should tell us more details about your camera, how it is connected and what OS and versions of all the software you use.

Comment: I am using the notebook camera (which is a Lenovo B50-70), this is Windows 8.1, PyCharm community 2018.3.6 and Python 3.7

Comment: Unlikely, but could this be an [aspect ratio](https://www.boxcast.com/blog/why-are-there-two-black-bars-on-the-sides-of-my-video-aspect-ratio) issue?

Comment: @furas When I'm normally using the camera, I have no problems, no black borders.

Comment: @plum0 I tried changing the ratio, but it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

```
camera = cv2.VideoCapture(cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
```

This should remove the border from the window.